# Unshare with --mount-proc creates a new mnt namespace

Tags: namespace, unshare

I am a little confused about what `--mount-proc` does when used with `unshare` command.

When I use `unshare -fp --mount-proc bash`, I notice that it results in both a new PID namespace and a new MNT namespace.

Given that I am in a new MNT namespace, I tried unmounting one of the loop devices and noticed that this was not reflected in the parent MNT (the mount still shows when I run `df -h` in the parent namespace).

Now, I went one step ahead, and, from within the new MNT namespace created a new root using `pivot_root`, and unmounted the original root. As expected, the new namespace now has a different root. The parent namespace still has the original root directory.

My Question: If I can achieve creating a new MNT namespace without using the `-m` option in the `unshare` command, and also achieve creating an isolated root directory for the new process, what different purpose does the MNT namespace serve?

I would be grateful for any guidance from the experts.

EDIT: I have modified my original post, which said that changing the root in the new namespace also changes the root in the parent namespace. I am no longer able to reproduce this. But my question on being able to create a new MNT namespace with just the `--mount-proc` option and without using `-m` with `unshare` still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`man unshare`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html)’s description of `--mount-proc` mentions

> It also implies creating a new mount
> namespace since the `/proc` mount would otherwise mess up
> existing programs on the system.

So in effect `--mount-proc` implies `-m`, with all the consequences you’ve seen. This isn’t something different, it is a new, private, mount namespace.

The `-m` option is still useful on its own since a new mount namespace can be useful without `/proc`.